# Create a modal popup

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite, modal-dialogs

I want to show a modal popup in drupal 7. On searching the web I came to know that it can be done using the ctools module itself. Here is the code I tried:

```
function codeexpertz_menu() {
  $items['codeexpertz/%ctools_js/page'] = array(
    'title' => 'Demo CTools Page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => 'codeexpertz_ctools_page_example',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function codeexpertz_ctools_page_example($js) {
  $output = "Sample CTools popup functionality for Demo purpose.";
  if ($js) {
    // Required includes for ctools to work:
    ctools_include('modal');
    ctools_include('ajax');
    return ctools_modal_render("Demo", $output);
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The link i referred is [here](http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-ctools-modal-popup-simple-page-example)

I added `<a href="codeexpertz/nojs/page" class="ctools-use-modal">Modal Window</a>` to my `page.tpl.php` file directly for now to test it. However when I click on the link I get redirected on the destination page rather than showing the content in a modal.

I tried this is a fresh installation also, but all in vain.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ctools_modal_text_button](https://api.drupal.org/api/ctools/includes%21modal.inc/function/ctools_modal_text_button/7.x-1.x) function to render your "popup-opener" links.

```
ctools_include('ajax');
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();
$link = ctools_modal_text_button('Open popup', 'codeexpertz/nojs/page', 'alt here', 'no-class');
```

You can have a look what the [Modal Entities](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/modal_entities/blob/7.x-1.x/modal_entities.module) modue does in the `modal_entities_generate_link()` function for additional style settings.